# How to clear the selected option when I change the options of a select?

Tags: reactjs, select

I defined a simple `MySelect` component to wrap the `select` component:

```
type Props = {
  options: { label: string, value: string }[]
}

export default function MySelect({options}: Props) {
  return <select size={3}>
    {options.map(it => {
      return <option value={it.value} key={it.value}>{it.label}</option>
    })}
  </select>
};
```

I have two options which has a common option (the `aaa` one):

```
const options1 = [{label: 'aaa', value: '111'}, {label: 'bbb', value: '222'}]
const options2 = [{label: 'aaa', value: '111'}, {label: 'ccc', value: '333'}]
```

When using `MySelect`, I provide a button to switch options:

```
export default function Hello() {
  const [options, setOptions] = useState(options1);

  return <div>
    <h1>Select 'aaa' then click on the "Switch Options" button</h1>
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => {
        if (options === options1) {
          setOptions(options2)
        } else {
          setOptions(options1)
        }
      }}>Switch Options
      </button>
    </div>
    <div><MySelect options={options}/></div>
  </div>
};
```

It looks like this:

[image]

The problem is, when I clicked the `aaa` option to select it:

[image]

then click "Switch Options" button to switch options, I hope the select to be reset with no selection, but the `aaa` is still selected:

[image]

Is there any way to let me clear the selected option?

A small working demo for this question: https://github.com/freewind-demos/typescript-react-clear-selected-option-demo

Answer (score 0):

This is a really good question. So I tried to debug this, and found this:

When we click the button only the options are changed and the `select` value remains the same. You can inspect the element and try clicking the button and see only the second option gets changed. Also for inspecting `value` you can choose the `select` element and on console type `$0.value`.

`Inspect` Screenshots:

[image: selecting the element]

[image: inspecting value]

**Solution**

1. Make `select` controlled and when the button is clicked reset the selected value.
2. Use `key={someValue}` on `select` and change this value on clicking the button. This would ensure the re-render of `select` and reset the value.

Hope this helps!

I am also looking for some great solution to this. Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks! About solution 1, I can't find a working way after several hours of research. Actually, I can use `ref` to get the reference of the select, and when the options are changed, I invoke `selectRef.current.value = ''` which clears the selection, but this is not an elegant way I think

Comment: You solution 2 is a good idea. If I set the key as `key={it.value + JSON.stringify(options)}` to make it different from all kinds of options, it will clear the selection. The problem is the performance issue for big arrays

Comment: I tried with making the component controlled and its weird that it doesnt even work and there is some inconsistency with React and DOM update. 
For solution `2` you can just use a string value instead of stringifying `options`

Comment: For solution 2, you're right, we can use some unique generated strings, or  hardcode some strings for different options